# What is consider fake in the subject of philosophy?

Tags: epistemology

What is consider fake in the subject of philosophy? In another word, what is pseudo-philosophy?

There is meaning of life, meaning of justice and meaning in money in philosophy, what is the definition of meaningless?

Comment: Is there any chance you could share a little bit more about what might have led you to asking about this? Is there anything in particular you might be reading or studying that might have motivated this, or made the problem seem interesting/important? What sort of hypotheses (if any) have you formed and what has your research turned up (if anything)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudophilosophy